# Chrome Developer tool debugger problem: Source Code is White (static) while debugging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently trying to debug my code without using `console.log()` or a similar a method. I want to see the variables dynamically so I can hover my mouse over them and see their values. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzFpW.png). However, not too long ago, Chrome Dev Tools stopped rendering some of the code as readable and dynamic so I can't see the values of the variables anymore ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMkpA.png)).

I already tried to restart chrome, my computer, clear cookies, Hard reload, Restore Dev Tools as default. What should I do now?

Comment: I also have run into a similar issue just this last week.  Wonder if there's a new bug in the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: Having a related isseu. Source is empty for the index file (JSP) and the debugger is not stopping at breakpoints in included javascript file.